# Tkinter Canvas Sense Touch?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a bit of a game, and I'm wondering if there's a way for a tkinter canvas object to detect if something's touching it. I currently use something like this:

```
pos = canvas.coords(insert_object_here)
otherpos = canvas.coords(other_object)    
if pos[3] <= objectpos[3] and pos[1] >= objectpos[1]:
    if pos[2] <= objectpos[0]:
        if pos[2] >= objectpos[0]-self.speed:
            canvas.move(self.id, -x, y)
    if pos[0] >= objectpos[2]:
        if pos[0] <= objectpos[2]+self.speed:
            canvas.move(self.id, -x, y)
if pos[2] <= objectpos[2] and pos[0] >= objectpos[0]:
    if pos[3] <= objectpos[1]:
        if pos[3] >= objectpos[1]-self.speed:
            canvas.move(self.id, x, -y)
    if pos[1] >= objectpos[3]:
        if pos[1] <= objectpos[3]+self.speed:
            canvas.move(self.id, x, -y)

canvas.move(self.id, x, y)
```

This is a lot of code, and I only need to use it once, making using a function pointless.

In summary, is there a way for an object to detect touch or at least is there a way to improve this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas has methods named `find_closest` and `find_overlapping` which can be used to determine if objects are touching or not.

Comment: how might I use these functions?